# IQR Score outliers detection in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas, numpy

I have a large dataset "train" incl. a column ClientFreeSource from which I want to exclude an outliers. For that purpose I decide to use IQR score.
I've tried:

```
Q1 = train['ClientFreeSources'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = train['ClientFreeSources'].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1

train = train[~((train['ClientFreeSources'] < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(train['ClientFreeSources'] > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
```

...which returns an error:

> ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type

I also tried to apply to score for no specific feature (whole dataset "train"), which returned:

> TypeError: Could not operate array([ nan]) with block values
>   unorderable types: str() < float()

Help would be appreciated.
I'm new to DS.